# Update OpenSSL 1.1.1 on Apache HTTPD

Tags: windows, apache, server, openssl

I've windows server with running apache httpd 2.4.54 with openssl 1.1.1p, I need to update openssl to 1.1.1q , How I can do ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Download 1.1.1q from https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000121705-openssl-3-0-and-1-1-1-binary-distributions-for-microsoft-windows

and replace your existing bin directory.

Restart Apache and it's done

Comment: Following these steps may result in the `openssl.exe` file not being properly associated with the OpenSSL configuration file.